# Bootstrap and angularjs: how not propagate the dropdown click on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

in bootstrap 3 and angularjs i have a list group and for every item i have a dropdown pulled right: when i click on the dropdown i'd like that only the dropdown menu is showed but the clicked event is propagated to the item

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" href="" class="list-group-item" ng-click="itemSelected(item)">
   {{item.Name}}
   <div class="dropdown pull-right" >
      <div href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="" style="font-size:80%">Edit</a></li>
         <li><a href="" style="font-size:80%">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

When i click on the dropdown i want that is showed only the dropdown element (Edit and Delete) and not called also the itemSelected() function

How can i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't just stop event from bubbling with event `stopPropagation` method, because Bootstrap's dropdown sets up click event listeners on the document level, so event bubbling is [necessary for dropdown](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L158) to be toggled. In this case you have two options.

**Option #1 (the best).** HTML restructuring. Wrap `{{item.Name}}` into one more container like `div` and put `ng-click="itemSelected(item)"` on it.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" href="" class="list-group-item">
   <div class="dropdown pull-right">
      <div href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="" style="font-size:80%">Edit</a></li>
         <li><a href="" style="font-size:80%">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div ng-click="itemSelected(item)">{{item.Name}}</div>
</div>
```

Note, that in this case you need to move `item.Name` div **after** `dropdown` one, in order to preserve correct float structure.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/q7BhKOH6RXzgMwI3T24p?p=preview

**Option #2.** Set a flag on the original event object saying that event occurred on dropdown toggle button. If this is the case upper `ngClick` handler would ignore this event.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" href="" class="list-group-item" ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown || itemSelected(item)">
    {{item.Name}}
    <div class="dropdown pull-right" ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown = true">
        <div href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="" style="font-size:80%">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" style="font-size:80%">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wgiSqkEEXDIKPnFPAbSK?p=preview

Comment: With ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" in the .dropdown div, the dropdown doesn't open when i click on the "caret"

Comment: Hoe do you init dropdown?